# Binding a Client Event to a Different Function

Tags: jquery

When a page is initially loaded I have the following `click` event setup (works fine):

```
$('#thisIsTheElement').click(function() {
  firstFunction();
});
```

At a later point (after something occurs) I want to change this click to point to a different function called

```
secondFunction();
```

what is the most efficient way to do this?

Should I unbind and bind again? Can this be done in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a flag to keep track whether `something` has occurred

```
var somethingOccurred = false;
$('#thisIsTheElement').click(function() {
    if(somethingOccurred){
        secondFunction();
    } else {
        firstFunction();
    }
});

//when something occurs
somethingOccurred = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be something like this:

```
$('#thisIsTheElement').on('click', firstFunction);
```

And later:

```
$('#thisIsTheElement').off('click', firstFunction).on('click', secondFunction);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xZzMD/

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/npwAz/82/)

[.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) documentation.

this code will toggle between two functions.

```
function firstFunction() {
    alert('First handler: ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).one("click", secondFunction);
}
function secondFunction() {
    alert('Second handler: ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).one("click", firstFunction);
}
$("div").one("click", firstFunction);
```

this code will run `firstFunction` one time and next time onward's `secondFunction`

```
function firstFunction() {
    alert('First handler: ' + $(this).text());
    $(this).on("click", secondFunction);
}
function secondFunction() {
    alert('Second handler: ' + $(this).text());
}
$("div").one("click", firstFunction);
```